# "Олбанский" сленг

Tags: сленг

Скажите, пожалуйста, а почему новомодный интернетсленг называется "олбанским" (от слова "албанский", как я понимаю)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В качестве версии:
~~~
Название «албанский» появилось в ЖЖ в 2004 году, и изначально с падонками никак не связано. Началось всё безобидно: некто Onepamop написал пост про то, как знатно побухал. В комментариях внезапно нарисовался совершенно незнакомый автору американец, который начал возбухать, почему это в его интернетах пишут на коммунистическом языке:

scottisht928: I cannot read that text. I knew I should have been a translator, after all. Please speak English. 
Над ним тут же прикололись:

scottisht928: Now tell me, what is this language they are speaking?! 
maxxximus: this is Albanian, i am only guessing what the fuck they are talking about.   something about how they were using new drugs or smthing 
Но шутки юный пиндос не понял и не остановился:

mypointofview: why do you think this text was written for you? 
scottisht928:Because? It's LIVEJOURNAL. An American website. Not an albanian; (#*!@()! site. Plus, being an American means that the rest of the world should have to cater to me. But that's just mypointofview. 
После такого наглого заявления русские устроили флешмоб: буржуя начали усердно задалбывать требованиями «выучить албанский» и извиниться, написав в своем журнале на русском, что он уже выучил албанский. В результате он получил за два дня десятки тысяч комментариев, его ящик был переполнен, а журнал заполнен кучей фанатиков, и он начал получать кучу SMS-ок и телефонных звонков, за которые вынужден был платить реальные деньги. В конце концов, бедняжка вынужден был сдаться и выполнить требование толпы, после чего удалил свой аккаунт из Жежешки.

При чём тут падонкафский? А ни при чём, просто история произошла как раз во времена его популярности. 
~~~
[тут](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2#.D0.9F.D0.BE.D1.87.D0.B5.D0.BC.D1.83_.D0.B0.D0.BB.D0.B1.D0.B0.D0.BD.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B8.D0.B9.3F)

Comment: Ссылочку под кат уберите, пожалуйста.

Comment: OK
А точно надо было?

Comment: Однозначно, т.к. разъежалась верстка страницы.

Comment: Я тремя браузерами пользуюсь - и словов-то таких не знаю.